# binary search tree traversal using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Q. I have questions regarding Binary search tree traversal using recursion and return. I have to take a BST with keys arranged in ascending order, and "reverse" it so all the keys are in descending order as you can see in the picture.

Based on my understanding of code below, I think the steps are:

```
  ->reverseKeys (10)  ->reverseKeys (2)
  ->reverseKeys (null): return 
  ->reversekeys(null): return 
  ->BSTNODE <T> ptr = root.left; 
  ->root.left = root.right;
  ->root.right = ptr;
```

I think I misinterpreted the code. Can someone expain how this code can change the picture on the left to the right? I would appreciate any help.

```
   25                 25 
  /  \               /  \ 
 10  40      --->   40   10 
 /\   /\           / \  / \ 
2 20 30 45        45 30 20  2 
 /    \              /   \
15    35            35   15 

 public static <T extends Comparable<T>> 
void reverseKeys(BSTNode<T> root) {
   if (root == null) { 
      return;
   }
   reverseKeys(root.left);
   reverseKeys(root.right);
   BSTNode<T> ptr = root.left;
   root.left = root.right;
   root.right = ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the BST - Reverse order traversal (RVL) of the below code

```
public void traverse (Node root){ // Each child of a tree is a root of its subtree.
    if (root.left != null){
        traverse (root.left);
    }
    System.out.println(root.data);
    if (root.right != null){
        traverse (root.right);
    }
}

// Search with a valid node returned, assuming int

public Node traverse (Node root, int data){ // What data are you looking for again?
    if(root.data == data) {
        return root;
    }
    if (root.left != null){
        return traverse (root.left, data);
    }
    if (root.right != null){
        return traverse (root.right, data);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These lines just swap left and right subtrees for a node. And because of recursive calls to the method every node has left and right subtrees swapped when method is executed.

```
BSTNode<T> ptr = root.left;
root.left = root.right;
root.right = ptr;
```